# Pandas replacing multiple words

Tags: pandas

**df**

```
col
a,b
b
c
b,c
```

**Goal**

- a→x, b→y, c→z

```
col 
x,y
y
z
y,z
```

**Try**

```
df['col']=df['col'].replace({'a':'x','b':'y','c':'z'})
```

It only works for one word, but multiple words like `x,y` failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameter `regex=True` for subtrings replacement:

```
df['col']=df['col'].replace({'a':'x','b':'y','c':'z'}, regex=True)
print (df)
   col
0  x,y
1    y
2    z
3  y,z
```

Another idea with `dictionary.get` for replace by splitted values and if no match get original value, last join back by `,`:

```
d = {'a':'x','b':'y','c':'z'}
df['col']=df['col'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(d.get(y, y) for y in x.split(',')))
print (df)
   col
0  x,y
1    y
2    z
3  y,z
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you could try using this piece of code:

```
>>> df['col'].str.split(',', expand=True).fillna('').replace({'a':'x','b':'y','c':'z'}).apply(','.join, axis=1).str.rstrip(',')
0    x,y
1      y
2      z
3    y,z
dtype: object
>>>
```